# Project compilation requires a class that is not used anywhere

Tags: java, gwt, ant, libgdx

When I build with `ant` my project that uses `libgdx`, I get a strange error. It says that a class `com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement` is not found, but it isn't used at all in the code. How can I find what makes this class necessary? Even searching over the whole project doesn't give any results. It says that error is at `PixmapTextureAtlas.java:16` ([class source](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=515)), but there is no code that uses that `ImageElement` class. Adding the library containing `com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement` class helps, of course, but I'd like to figure out why this class in needed.

Here is the place in ant log that tells of the actual error:

```
Compiling 3 source files to /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/bin
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/src/org/tendiwa/client/PixmapTextureAtlas.java:16: error: cannot access ImageElement
class file for com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement not found
```

Here is the whole ant log:

```
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Xmx128m -Xss2m -Dant.home=/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant -Dant.library.dir=/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-jai.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/opt/intellijidea/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2 -logger com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaAntLogger2 -inputhandler com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.IdeaInputHandler -buildfile /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/build.xml jar
build.xml
property
path
description
compile
ant
property
property
property
description
compile
mkdir
javac
jar
ant
property
description
_core_src_available
available
ontology
antcall
property
description
_core_src_available
available
_build_core
ant
property
property
compile
echo
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client
mkdir
javac
jar
jar
Building jar: /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/MainModule.jar
description
tempfile
mkdir
Created dir: /tmp/tendiwa373148820
unjar
Expanding: /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/MainModule.jar into /tmp/tendiwa373148820
Expanding: /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/tendiwa-backend.jar into /tmp/tendiwa373148820
Expanding: /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/tendiwa-ontology.jar into /tmp/tendiwa373148820
copy
Copying 1 file to /tmp/tendiwa373148820
java
Created item short_sword
Created item short_bow
Created item bucket
Created item boot
Created item steel_morningstar
Created item rifle_ammo
Created item handAxe
Created item iron_armor
Created item steel_mace
Created item jacket
Created item fedora
Created item wooden_arrow
Saving sources to /tmp/tendiwa373148820/ontology/src
tendiwa/resources/SoundTypes.java
tendiwa/resources/CharacterTypes.java
tendiwa/resources/ObjectTypes.java
tendiwa/resources/FloorTypes.java
tendiwa/resources/ItemTypes.java
tendiwa/resources/MaterialTypes.java
mkdir
mkdir
mkdir
Created dir: /tmp/tendiwa373148820/ontology/bin
javac
jar
Building jar: /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/tendiwa-ontology.jar
echo
Resources source code generated
ant
property
property
compile
echo
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client
mkdir
javac
jar
jar
jar
Building jar: /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/MainModule.jar
mkdir
javac
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/build.xml:25: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/build.xml (25:46)'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
Compiling 3 source files to /home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/bin
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/src/org/tendiwa/client/PixmapTextureAtlas.java:16: error: cannot access ImageElement
class file for com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement not found
1 error
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/build.xml:25: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
/home/suseika/Projects/tendiwa/client/build.xml:25: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)

Ant build completed with 3 errors one warning in 4s at 10/30/13 3:09 AM
```

Here is a part of ant file where this error appears:

```
<path id="tendiwa.jars">
    <fileset dir="../libs">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="../tendiwa-backend.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="../tendiwa-ontology.jar"/>
    <!--<fileset dir="/usr/share/java" includes="gwt*.jar"/>-->
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <ant dir="../MainModule" target="jar"/>
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <javac destdir="bin" failonerror="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="tendiwa.jars"/>

            <!--temporary-->
            <pathelement path="../tendiwa-ontology.jar"/>
            <!--temporary-->
            <pathelement path="../MainModule.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="../libs" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <src>
            <pathelement path="Desktop/src"/>
            <pathelement path="src"/>
        </src>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why that was happening. I accidentally added to classpath two different jars where are two different variants of class `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap`, one having dependency on GWT, and another being the one I needed. The problem was that I didn't know such situation is possible : )

Answer (score 2):

A given library may have dependencies that it does not provide, so your code needs it *indirectly*. `PixmapTextureAtlas.java:16` does reference this class, and you use `PixmapTextureAtlas`, therefore you indirectly need `com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement`.

A tool like Maven can add dependencies/subdependencies and manage them easily.

Comment: Actually, it does reference `com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement`, but it probably shouldn't. I guess I asked the wrong question, irrelevant in my situation.